# Performing calculation on objects from another class

Tags: python

I have created a class to hold objects with data being written into them from another class using lists. I want to now create a class to import those objects perform a calculation with the data they contain and then write the results to new objects.

```
class Calculation(object):
    def __init__(self, A, B, C, Flag):
        self.A = A
        self.B = B
        self.C = C
        self.Flag = Flag

    def calcA():
        pass

    def calcB():
        pass

    def calcC():
        pass

    def setFlag():
        pass
```

Above is the Calculation class

```
class CreateObjects():
    #This object holds all the data for one Item
    def __init__(self, OjectID, ObjectPrice, ObjectNum, Objectzone, ObjectTicket, Multiplier):
        self.OjectID= OjectID
        self.ObjectPrice= ObjectPrice
        self.ObjectTicket= ObjectTicket
        self.ObjectNum= ObjectNum
        self.Objectzone= Objectzone
        self.Multiplier = Multiplier
```

How can I get this data into my new class and then perform calculations on each item and write it back to the new object. For example `ObjectPrice/ ObjectNum * Multiplier`.

Comment: Why not defining your `calc<x>` functions inside the `CreateObject` class?

Comment: @toti08 I'm adding data to those objects in the CreateObject class using something similar to this  'inputyObjects = [CreateObjects(ID, Price, Ticket, Num, Zone, Multiplier) for ID, Price, Ticket, Num,  Zone, Multiplier in zip(IdList, PriceList, TicketList)]'  and didn't want to have to add extra parameters to this

Comment: Whay would you need an extra parameter? The instantiation of the object would be the same, only difference is that you would then do your calculations on the object itself instead of using another class...

Comment: @toti08 Do you mean set up a new function within the class to declare the calculation objects?

Comment: yes, I mean moving your `calcA`, `calcB`, etc... function to the `CreateObjects` class...would that work?

Comment: @toti08 I will need to store the results back into the objects set up in the calculation class

Comment: What if you do your calculation at instantiation time? So by calling your `calc` methods in the `__init__`?

Comment: @toti08 Im not sure what you mean, I need both the objects in the calculation class and CreateObjects to then create a csv using each one as a column